# Navigate to a separate browser from Gridview Hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello I would like the user to be directed to a separate browser if possible from a HyperLink in a Gridview. How can I do this.. like you know how a href blah blah target:_blank something like that.. but the problem is that I am using this..

```
   <asp:HyperLinkField 
DataNavigateUrlFields="myID" 
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="../names/view.aspx?myID={0}" //anyway to do it here?
DataTextField="name" 
HeaderText="Name" 
SortExpression="Name" 
ItemStyle-Width="100px"
ItemStyle-Wrap="true" 
HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Target property:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="myID" 
                    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="../names /view.aspx?myID={0}"
                    DataTextField="name" 
                    HeaderText="Name" 
                    SortExpression="Name" 
                    ItemStyle-Width="100px" 
                    ItemStyle-Wrap="true" 
                    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                    Target="_blank" />
```

Comment: Great this works, is there any way I could modify the size of the window being targeted?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of through the HyperLinkField control.  If the above answer works for you, please consider accepting it.  Thanks. :)

Comment: sure, I always do.. just was wondering if you knew how to resize the targeted window thanks